# What does "$\times$" mean when specifying the domain of a function?

Tags: functions, notation

Just a quick question on function notation. If specifying the function like this: $$f : X \times X \to Y,$$

what does the '$\times$' symbol mean exactly? Does it mean that 2 elements of domain $X$ are combined via some relation '$\times$' to give an element of codomain $Y$ or does it somehow represent a Cartesian product of the two sets, namely $X^2$. In the latter case I don't know what the above specification means.

Comment: The [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). It is the same as the notation $X^2$.

Comment: For example a function $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} x \mapsto x \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ can be also written as $$f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \ (x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 + x_2.$$

Comment: So in the case of my question the function would look like $f(x,y)$ for some $x,y \in X$? Basically just means that the function takes 2 parameters?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Basically, except one would say that the function takes a single parameter from $X^2$ (which contains ordered pairs from $X$).

Comment: That's basically how we *define* a function taking two parameters.  The definition of  a function maps a *single* value from a domain to a single value of a co-domain.  How can multiple parameters be considered a single value?  Well, because the pair $(x,y)$ is a single value of an ordered pair.  What is the set of all possible ordered pairs?  The cartesian product of two sets.  So $f:X\times X \to Y$ means that if $z=(x,y) \in X\times X$ then $f(z) = f((x,y))$ has a value in $Y$.  The notation $f(x,y)$ to mean $f(x)$ where $z=(x,y)$ is just convenient and harmless shorthand.

Comment: Technically speaking:  A function with "multiple parameters" is an oxymoron.  A function maps values, and a single value is a single value.  But we can get around it by considered the collection of multiple parameters as a single value in the Set of all possible collections of multiple values.  Then $f:$ All possible collections of multiple values of $X\to Y$. And $X\times X$, the cartesian product, is *precisely* $=$ The Set of all Ordered Pairs of X.

Comment: The only thing that was confusing me is $f((x,y))$. Makes me think that the function must act on that ordered pair directly, not with its elements. Like Viktor's first line. But a function taking two or more parameters is just a function that takes an $n$-tuple as a parameter and if we supply it an $n$-tuple then that's it. $f((x,y,z)) = f(x,y,z)$

Answer (score 4):

As comments have noted, $A\times B:=\{(a,\,b)|a\in A,\,b\in B\}$. With $|S|$ denoting the number of elements of a set $S$, this notation has the motivation $|A\times B|=|A|\times|B|$.

As for the question of whether one should write $f(a,\,b)$ or $f((a,\,b))$, the former is usually used because it looks neater, but *conceptually* the latter has the advantage that we can define all functions in the same way. In particular, a function $f$ can be regarded as a set of ordered pairs with$$(u,\,v)\in f,\,(u,\,w)\in f\implies v=w.$$This does require identifying $u$ with $(a,\,b)$, though. The alternative would be to say that a function that "take two arguments" has a domain of the form $(A,\,B)$, and is a set of ordered triples with$$(q,\,r,\,s),\,(q,\,r,\,t)\in f\implies s=t.$$Such a context-dependent definition of what functions are under the hood isn't worth the hassle it would create in more complicated examples.

There's actually another way to think of all functions as [having only one argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity#Unary), called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), after Haskell Curry. The idea is to regard a "function of $k$ arguments" as a function of one argument, which returns a function of $k-1$ arguments. In particular, is $S^T$ denotes the set of functions from $T$ to $S$ (so that $|S^T|=|S|^{|T|}$), each $f\in C^{A\times B}$ can be thought of as an element of $(C^B)^A$. That's not too surprising, since$$|C|^{|A|\times|B|}=\left(|C|^{|B|}\right)^{|A|}.$$

Comment: Can you give example for this equation $|A\times B|=|A|\times|B|$? Suppose $|A|=3, |B|=4$?

Comment: @MichaelMunta If $A=\{a_1,\,a_2,\,a_3\},\,B=\{b_1,\,b_2,\,b_3,\,b_4\}$ then $$A\times B=\{(a_1,\,b_1),\,(a_1,\,b_2),\,(a_1,\,b_3),\,(a_1,\,b_4),\,(a_2,\,b_1),\,(a_2,\,b_2),\,(a_2,\,b_3),\,(a_2,\,b_4),\,(a_3,\,b_1),\,(a_3,\,b_2),\,(a_3,\,b_3),\,(a_3,\,b_4)\}.$$

Comment: Ah so the $\times$ sign on the right side actually means multiply?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Well, there's no other kind of $\times$ that fits between integers.